# Integrating recyclerview with database

Tags: java, android, database, arraylist, swap

```
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            Collections.swap(queuee, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());

            // and notify the adapter that its dataset has changed
            adapterr.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
```

With the above code i m able to swap the items in the recyclerview ,but now the problem is i also want to make the same respective changes to database.
How to go about?

queuee receives the all the data from the database
queuee is a arraylist which is used to set the recyclerview adapter

Regards
Thanks

Comment: This very much depends on what kind of database you have, and what your writing-on-db approach is

Answer (score 0):

Adapter:

```
    public class QueueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QueueAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    public ArrayList<Music> queue;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public TextView title,tt,artist;
        public Button play,stop;
        public ImageButton option;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songtitle1);
            artist = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.artist1);
            //  play = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.play);
            // stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stop);
            // tt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
            option = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option1);




        }
    }

    public QueueAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Music> queue) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.queue_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Music mu1 = queue.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(mu1.getTitle());
        holder.artist.setText(mu1.getArtist());
        final String link =mu1.getUrl();
        final String SongName = mu1.getTitle();


    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return queue.size();
    }



    public void removeItem(int position) {
        queue.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, queue.size());
    }


}
```

activity:

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerqueue);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());





    adapterr = new QueueAdapter(this,queuee);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    // adapterr.
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterr);
   initSwipe();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can do it on `OnDestroy` method in your Activity. Specifically speaking, firstly, you can get all your data from your adapter, and then delete datas in your database, at last, you can save your data obtained from your adapter again. In this moment, the sequence of your datas is what you want, and this way is easy to code. I'd rather you don't
update your database during `onMove`, because it's too frequently during your drag, and operates all data is easier than two datas in database.